# Karate HTML Report is not generated if there is a feature with @ignore tag

Tags: karate

I have two simple features on my project. One has the @ignore tag. When I run Karate project, everything is OK but HTML report is not generated, I mean that on the console there is no message like this:

```
HTML Report: (paste into browser to view) | Karate version:*.*.*
file:.../karate-summary.html
```

And the karate-summary.html file is not generated.

This problem is happening on the v1.1.0 and the v1.2.0.RC1 but it's working on the v1.0.0

So I don't know if this is a "feature" of the latest releases or is a "bug".

(It's important to say that if I delete the @ignore tag, it works)

Answer (score 0):

Yes `@ignore` [became a "built-in" tag in 1.1.0](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/1817) - so if needed use some other tag instead of `@ignore` if you want to get the benefit of tags for selecting some tests to run etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I don't understand what means "built-in" at all and why it must affect the generation of the karate-summary.html -  I have tried also with my own tags like @skipme and using the right command (mvn test "-Dkarate.options=--tags ~@skipme" -Dtest=...) but the karate-summary.html is not generated.

Comment: @AbelDuránGuerrero so my response is that "it works for me". so please follow the instructions in my second link exactly as described